# C++ - websocket client n server

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket, socket.io, wss

Please suggest me in creating websocket client and server in c++?
im using gcc 4.4 and also i need to know whether both ws and wss can be done.

Please provide any tutorial sites or sample code to use.

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome C++ WebSocket library, hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp).
And there's [manual](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/).